# How do I set the value of a text input field when the field does not have an id but it has a name. I can't use document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am try to set the value of an input field for which i can not assign an ID so I can't use document.getElementById.  Is there any other way I can assign a value to this text input field that has a name?

Comment: use a queryselector `document.querySelector('[name=value]')` or just `document.querySelector('[name]')`

Comment: If the field has a name 'x' in a form named 'f', then `document.f.x`.

Comment: Thank you and everyone else below who answered my question.  I have tried the recommendations and I have my code working.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

```
const el = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
el.value = 'someValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a basic [queryselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select attributes and to do so, you need to put the attributes name between brackets `[` and `]`. The attributes can have an optional value too by using an equal sign.

Here is a working example:

```js
document.querySelector('[name=hello]').value = 'Hello World'
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="hello">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.getElementsByname()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName).

This method returns an array of elements, so you might want to access the first element in the array.

**Live Example:**

```js
var myInput = document.getElementsByName("my-input")[0];

myInput.value = "Some Text";
```

```html
<input type="text" name="my-input">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input field, named 'x', for example, is in a form  with name 'f' for example, then:

`document.f.x.value = 'some value';`

```js
function test()
{
    document.f.x.value = 'It works!';
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="f">
  <input name="x" size="20">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="test();">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```